# Fetch correct VRAM for GPU via Command Line on Windows

Tags: command-line, memory, graphics-card, gpu

I have a program which I run on hundreds of different computers a day, this is sort of like an inventory program. One of the details I'm trying to fetch is the amount of VRAM available to the graphics card.

I'm currently using WMIC to do this, specifically the `win32_VideoController` path, and the `AdapterRAM` value. This works great on any computer which has less than 4GB of VRAM (Which most do, but not all)

Recently we got some computers with 1060 & 1080 graphics cards, these have more than 4GB VRAM. `Win32_VideoController` returns the AdapterRAM value as a data type: `uint32`, which basically means that it is unable to return anything over 4GB.

I've been looking around online trying to find another way to get the VRAM for the GPU (I have to be able to do it with a command), but can only find people using `Win32_VideoController` in really old questions/answers.

How can I get the *correct* amount of VRAM from a computer via command line? I can use a 3rd party program if it is small enough if I have to.

Comment: On such computers, test if the command `wmic.exe PATH Win32_videocontroller GET AdapterRAM` doesn't return multiple entries, each one up to 4GB, summing up to the real total.

Comment: @harrymc It doesn't return multiple values for the same graphics card. In the example I tested it on, it returned 2 different values but that's because it has an onboard AND a graphics card, but adding these up does not equal the correct amount of VRAM from the graphics card.

Comment: I wish I had enough rep (or could use my rep from SO) to start a bounty on this :/ just 13 views in 2 days

Comment: My opinion at the moment is that the Windows utilities have not been updated to 64-bit so can't show more than 4GB. I think one has to query the display driver via Windows API for this information.

Comment: @harrymc Is there any way you know of to do that via command prompt or node.js (Electron)?

Comment: No, I don't. It might be in DirectX API, but I don't know that one.

Answer (score 2):

```
$qwMemorySize = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0*" -Name HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)."HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize"
[math]::round($qwMemorySize/1GB)
```

Comment: Because the VRAM size also stores in "HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0*" so you can retrive its' value and convert it into GB. The whole code: [link](https://github.com/farag2/PC-information/blob/master/PC.ps1#L174)